# Getting the next element Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I created a link which when the user click into, I want to alert the next element content. Below, you can see that the class "link" is the link itself. My goal is to get the content of the "book", "paper", "drinks", and "videos" class just by using the $(this) method.

```
<td><a href="#" class="link">This is a Link</a></td>
<td><span class="book">This is a book</span></td>
<td><span class="paper">This is a paper</span></td>
<td><span class="drinks">This is a book</span></td>'
<td><span class="videos">This is a videos</span></td>'
```

I've done doing something like the code below, but it seems it couldnt reach the classes since 'a' is not of a siblings of these classes because they are wrap with `<td>` which their original parents. Is there any way to handle this?

```
$('a').click(function(){
               var books = $(this).siblings('.book').html();
                   var paper = $(this).siblings('.paper ').html();
                   var drinks = $(this).siblings('.drinks').html();
                   var videos= $(this).siblings('.videos').html();

                  alert(books);
            });
```

Comment: Those aren't siblings (children of the same parent). Consider something like https://github.com/techfoobar/jquery-next-in-dom - *Disclaimer: I am the author*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just crawl up to a common ancestor like this...

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var books = $(this).closest("tr").find(".book").html();
});
```

Comment: But the thing is, I have multiple books classes with different content. Therefore, I want to just the NEXT book class content next to $(this) class.

Comment: Ah, I see.  If you have it, do you mind modifying the answer?

Comment: Sorry, I just thought you meant that you found a different answer.  Glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of what I guess you're trying to do:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    var next = $(this).parent().next().html()
    //alert(next);
    console.log(next);
});
```

for more info: http://jsfiddle.net/juaning/7tDKZ/